# Determining which version of the NFS protocol is in use by a mounted NFS filesystem

Tags: nfs

I mounted an NFS filesytem from the shell using the code:

```
LINE='nfs.francky.me:/export/beatdb /beatdb nfs tcp,intr,rw 0 0'
grep "$LINE" /etc/fstab >/dev/null || echo $LINE >> /etc/fstab
mkdir /beatdb
mount -a # Remount /etc/fstab Without Reboot in Linux
```

How can I determining which version of the NFS protocol is in use?

I tried using `nfsstat -c` as well as `rpcinfo -p nfs.francky.me`, my understanding is that the latter shows that the server supports version 2 and 3 of the NFS protocol, but I don't know which one is been used. I don't have access to the NFS server so I am looking for a solution client-side.

[image]